# transforming data from one sql server DB to another

Tags: sql-server

I need to transform data from one DB to another. Both DB's are on different physical servers. Normally I'd just write a cursor, but I cannot do that in this instance as cursors require the DB's to be on the same and serverinstance at least. The tables are not in the same structure, so I cant do a straight copy. I was  going to use SSIS, but powers here, dont want me to use it

Comment: add a linked server and execute insert ... select ... statement.

Comment: Opposed to SSIS? tell them to use Excel! <sarcasm off> Is a linked server acceptable? Please dont say no, or the powers over there may want you to use a fax machine and a data entry person. ;)